# Mappings cannot be assigned to error Solidity

Tags: solidity, remix, mapping

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.7.0;

contract Bid{

    mapping(string=>uint) propertyVoteCount;
    mapping(string=>mapping(string => bool)) propertyUserVoted;
    
    function vote(string memory propertyId, string memory userId)public returns (bool){
        require(propertyVoteCount[propertyId]<10, "Bidding is Over");
        mapping (string => bool) storage userIds = propertyUserVoted[propertyId];
        require(!userIds[userId], "User has already voted");
        propertyVoteCount[propertyId]++;
        userIds[userId] = true;
        propertyUserVoted[propertyId] = userIds; //Getting the error here

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are assigning the all mapping instead of assigning a value to an element of the mapping.

Couldn't you achieve the same thing with the code below? Why the added complexity? Did you find that code somewhere?

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.7.0;

contract Bid{

    mapping(string=>uint) public propertyVoteCount;
    mapping(string=>mapping(string => bool)) public propertyUserVoted;
    
    function vote(string memory propertyId, string memory userId)public returns (bool){
        require(propertyVoteCount[propertyId]<10, "Bidding is Over");
        require(!propertyUserVoted[propertyId][userId], "User has already voted");
        propertyVoteCount[propertyId]++;
        propertyUserVoted[propertyId][userId] = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: But, by technically speaking, why we couldn't make such assignment? It is possible in other languages, e.g. Java\Kotlin.